# SQL Code Execution

Tags: sql

in the code below it seems that SQL is performing a calculation with a variable that is still not defined in the current context:

```
Abs([MVE_UP_100]/([MARKET_VALUE]*0.01)) AS MODIFIED_DURATION, 
Sum(cst_sum_crosstab_intereses2.MVE_UP_100) AS MVE_UP_100,
```

As you see MVE_UP_100 is defined after the first line is executed, so I don't know why the code still does the calculation.

Any help?

Comment: Do you mind posting the complete query? So far, MVE_UP_100 seems to a column available in cst_sum_crosstab_intereses2 table/view/subquery

Comment: Hello, the issue is that MVE_UP_100 is not defined in any line before this lines of codes, so I don't know where it gets the value from.

Comment: It is available as a column in one of the tables/subqueries in your SELECT statement. It would be more clear if you post the complete query.

Answer (score 2):

Because MVE_UP_100 is a field name in cst_sum_crosstab_intereses2, so it is defined already but its content would be different that the contents of your aliased field

Comment: MVE_UP_100 field will give an error if you are using it with the aggregate as well as without it...